# How to build undirected graph from city vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have citie's location, I treat the cities as vertex. I want to created 
undirected graph to later to calculate shortest path tree. My question is 
how to create undirected graph for the cities first?

Comment: Do you have information about roads/pathes between cities?

Comment: I can get the distance and travel time between those cities. It means the paths between cities can be found.

Comment: This question can be more generalized to creating an undirected graph or data structure for undirected graph.

Answer (score 1):

Graph consists of vertices and edges. So your task is to gather information about edges somehow.

If you don't have information about which cities are directly connected to which neighboring cities by plain road (with no cities in between), then you might use some heuristic assumption. For example, you could safely assume that each city has no more than N (let's say N=50) roads going out of it and then just fill your graph with edges that represent roads to N closest neighboring cities.

To find those, you could take all cities surrounding a certain city, for example in radius of M miles (let's say M=100), and out of those pick no more than N closest ones. Those city pairs would represent roads in your graph.

Comment: His question is, how to create an undirected graph from vertices or nodes.

Comment: @kishore, the graph cannot have only vertices. To calculate shortest path you've got to have edges (roads between cities). My understanding is that he doesn't have clean data about roads, so I answer how else he can gather this data and add to his graph. Your answer, on the other hand, is about representation of graph edges in computer memory.

Answer (score 0):

Generally graphs are created using `Adjacency Matrix` or `Adjacency List`, whether they are weighed or non-weighed.

Adjacency matrix is a simple 2D array `edge[n][n]` where n are the number of vertices and `edge[a][b] = 1 or weight` represents a connection between a & b nodes.
`edge[a][b] = 0` means no connection. Adjacency Matrix is always symmetric for undirected graphs.

Depending on the type of application you may want to switch between Adjacency Matrix or Adjacency List. The former has less time complexity in graph operations but requires more space compared to the later.

You can find more about Adjacency Matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix)